# What's the best way to properly transition the rectangles, back and forth, horizontally, and indefinitely in D3?

Tags: d3.js, transition, rectangles

**Original Code and Visualization is located at:** http://bl.ocks.org/Guerino1/6aa3861bcbe96c343103

I am trying to chain transitions for rectangles.  When I transition, I believe I am overwriting the "x" attribute, using the code:

```
      rectangle.transition()
        .ease("linear")
        .duration(1500)
        .attr("x", function(){ 
          if(x == orig_x){
            var retVal =  dataSet.svgWidth-Number(width);
            return retVal;
          }
          else{
            var retVal = Number(orig_x);
            return retVal;
          }
        })
```

**The issue seems to be** that the above code does not overwrite the "x" value, when the transition is executed, the first time.  As I step through the debugger, the next time I step through the flip() function, "x" is still set to its original value, even though it appears that retValue returned a different value the last time through (for that specific rectangle).  NOTE: I use different colors to be sure I'm working with consistent rectangles.

This code is wrapped in a function called "flip()" that is called by a while loop that is intended to flip the value of "x" back and forth between the original value of "x" (stored in "orig_x") and the width of the svg canvas minus the original width of the rectangle.  The intent is a visualization that causes the rectangles to keep shifting "horizontally," back and forth.

The original data set is:

```
  var dataSet7 = [];
    dataSet7.svgWidth = 400;
    dataSet7.svgHeight = 95;
    dataSet7.r1 = {"x": 0, "y": 0, "w": 50, "h": 30, "color": "Red"};
    dataSet7.r2 = {"x": 10, "y": 30, "w": 150, "h": 30, "color": "Yellow"};
    dataSet7.r3 = {"x": 20, "y": 60, "w": 90, "h": 30, "color": "Blue"};
```

The HTML div that gets replaced with the chart is:

```
      <td class="td_tableBody" colspan="1">
        <div class="div_RootBody">
          <h3 class="h3_Body">Continuous Transition</h3>
          <p>Transitions the x-axis continuously.</p>
          <div id="simple_rectangle9"></div>
        </div>
      </td>
```

The for the function that gets called is:

```
      function drawRectangle9( dataSet, selectString ) {

function flip(){
      var rectangle = d3.select(this);
      var width = rectangle.attr("width");
      var x = rectangle.attr("x");
      var orig_x = rectangle.attr("orig_x");
          // Just for debug info...
          var y = rectangle.attr("y");
          var height = rectangle.attr("height");
          var color = rectangle.attr("color");
      rectangle.transition()
        .ease("linear")
        .duration(1500)
        .attr("x", function(){ 
          if(x == orig_x){
            var retVal =  dataSet.svgWidth-Number(width);
            return retVal;
          }
          else{
            var retVal = Number(orig_x);
            return retVal;
          }
        })
    };

    // Extract Rectangles from dataSet
    var rectangles = [];
      rectangles[0] = dataSet.r1;
      rectangles[1] = dataSet.r2;
      rectangles[2] = dataSet.r3;

    var svgContainer = d3.select(selectString).append("svg:svg")
        .attr("width", dataSet.svgWidth)
        .attr("height", dataSet.svgHeight);

    var arrayOfRectangles = svgContainer.selectAll("rect")
        .data(rectangles)
      .enter().append("svg:rect")
        .attr("class", "rect_flip1")
        .attr("x", function(d){ return d.x; })
        .attr("orig_x", function(d){ return d.x; })
        .attr("y", function(d){ return d.y; })
        .attr("width", function(d){ return d.w; })
        .attr("height", function(d){ return d.h; })
        .attr("color", function(d){ return d.color; })
        .style("fill", function(d){ return d.color; });

    var i = 0;
    while(i++ < 10){
      var rectangles = d3.selectAll(".rect_flip1")
      rectangles.each(flip);
    }

  }
```

The function call that executes the above function is:

```
drawRectangle9(dataSet7, "#simple_rectangle9");
```

**My Question:** What's the best way to properly transition the rectangles, back and forth horizontally, indefinitely?

Comment: you might take a look at Scott Murray's presentation on transitions: http://alignedleft.com/projects/2014/easy-as-pi/

Comment: The advice was very good.  I corrected the code, based on the tutorial, and it works correctly.  I copied and pasted the corrected code below.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advice from ee2Dev was good but not specific.  Below is the specific code that corrects the problem.

The solution is to create a function that loops back on itself using the "`.each("end", flip)`" method.  Then, trigger the function with one single call of that function (e.g. "`flip();`").

```
  function drawRectangle9( dataSet, selectString ) {

    // Extract Rectangles from dataSet
    var rectangles = [];
      rectangles[0] = dataSet.r1;
      rectangles[1] = dataSet.r2;
      rectangles[2] = dataSet.r3;

    var svgContainer = d3.select(selectString).append("svg:svg")
        .attr("width", dataSet.svgWidth)
        .attr("height", dataSet.svgHeight);

    var arrayOfRectangles = svgContainer.selectAll("rect")
        .data(rectangles)
      .enter().append("svg:rect")
        .attr("class", "rect_flip1")
        .attr("x", function(d){ return d.x; })
        .attr("orig_x", function(d){ return d.x; })
        .attr("y", function(d){ return d.y; })
        .attr("width", function(d){ return d.w; })
        .attr("height", function(d){ return d.h; })
        .attr("color", function(d){ return d.color; })
        .style("fill", function(d){ return d.color; });

    var flip = function(){
      var selectedRectangles = d3.selectAll(".rect_flip1");
      selectedRectangles.transition()
        .ease("linear")
        .duration(1500)
        .attr("x", function(d,i){ 
            var rect = d3.select(this)
            var x = rect.attr("x")
            var orig_x = rect.attr("orig_x")
            var width = rect.attr("width")
          if(x == orig_x){
            var retVal = dataSet.svgWidth-width;
            return retVal;
          }
          else{
            var retVal = orig_x;
            return retVal;
          }
        })
        .each("end", flip);
    };

    flip();

  }
```